# Without Avatar, can I spend Quintessence in any way to cast spells?

Tags: world-of-darkness, mage-the-ascension, quintessence

I'm reading Mage: The Ascension (I believe it's second edition). The description of the Avatar background says that "the rank of Avatar also represents the limit of Quintessence points that a Mage can channel for a effect".

So, if a Mage doesn't has Avatar, it cannot:

- Cast spells that create matter. Can they create fireball and stuff?
- Use Quintessence to lower spell difficulty.

Considering if this is true, a Mage with a Tass available cannot use its Quintessence in case they absorb it? Quintessence has pratically no value if you don't have Avatar?

Comment: Hi, Bruno! I've answered your question, but there's more information at the [tag:quintessence] tag which might help.

Comment: Related: [What does it mean to not have points in avatar?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/201525)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Mages with an Avatar rating of zero (which is different from not having an awakened avatar, but I imagine that's clear to you) can [use Quintessence in the form of tass so long as they have Prime of 1](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/169677/what-level-of-prime-is-required-to-use-tass). They can also gather quintessence by [burning their pattern, gaining one point of quint for each level of aggravated damage they take](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/183612/how-can-a-mage-gain-quintessence-besides-gathering-at-a-node).

Spells that involve creating something from nothing — Matter, Life, or Forces — do require Prime 2. However, without it, you can still use those Spheres to craft or shape existing material for your use. A Mage with Forces 3 and Prime 2 can conjure a lightning bolt from the air — but one with Forces 2 can pull the electricity from a power main for a similar effect.